# Opencl FFT libraries? Anything new or under the radar out there?

Tags: opencl, fft, nvidia

I googled this topic and didn't find anything new. I am aware of Nvidia's FFT implementation which is great, but for CUDA only. AMD just released their implementation, but it doesn't work on Nvidia cards. Apple has an older and slower implementation. Are there any other good FFT libraries out there? It would be nice if there was an implementation that was meant to work on Nvidia and AMD cards and other possible platforms and is being actively maintained.

Comment: are you sure about all the assertions here?  amd opencl code should work with cuda and the apple fft code is based on work that was faster than cuda - see http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/ (comments at bottom of page).

Answer (score 3):

The AMD clAmdFft library ***should*** work on NVidia GPUs.

I was involved in the development and I know that was the intention.  The code was written to the OpenCL standard and doesn't use any proprietary tricks.  Of course, AMD didn't do QA testing on NVidia hardware.  It could be that NVidia's OpenCL implementation isn't quite 100% compliant to the standard yet.  Or it could be something about your particular video card.

Please post more details here as to exacly what is happening.  You should also post that information in the AMD developer forums as a bug.

Comment: Just did some testing clAmdBlas and clAmdFft both work on nvidia and intel architectures too. The problem though, you need AMD APP SDK during compile time and runtime. Apparently they use some symbols only found in the libOpenCL.so packaged in there.

Answer (score 1):

AMD recently released [an OpenCL SDK](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/AMDAPPSDK/Pages/default.aspx) for their CPUs as wel as GPUs. Included in it are FFT and BLAS libraries. You can go to the bottom of the page to find out about the supported devices.

But I am not really sure about the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet - but there is a project to port the [GSL (Gnu Scientific Library)](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) to opencl
http://gsl-cl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: GSL looks like a huge library. I am guessing it will take quite an effort for it to reach a good state?

Answer (score 0):

I know Apple has released an OpenCL FFT package, but I don't know much about it.  I've heard that they make the source available.